# About WordPress child theme path

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about wordpress child-theme.

I am trying to modify wc-template-hooks.php in child-theme.

The path of the file is as follows.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php
```

I copied this file to the child-theme path and it does not apply.

```
/wp-content/themes/(child-theme)/wc-template-hooks.php
or
/wp-content/themes/(child-theme)/includes/wc-template-hooks.php
```

Comment: Themes won't 'override' just any old plugin file that you add in there, only template files and even then, only if the plugins supports it.

Comment: You can only override files inside template folder in woocommerce

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to modify `wc-template-hooks`? You can simply add your own or remove/modify the included hooks in your `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the templates folder from WooCommece for example: To override the admin order notification, copy: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

If you wish to modify the hooks then, you can use i.e.

```
// Remove functions from woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook with original priority
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
// Added functions to woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook with new priority
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 5 );
```